# How to "return the environment" from `with`

Tags: r

I am using R to scrub data. I have a dataset with 1,000s of columns all of which have some modification. I find the `$` operator makes my code unreadable. I like to do data steps with the `with` command, so that all the elements of the data frame are locally scoped (forgive my near complete ignorance of computer science here). However, after all is done, I would like to return all the variables I wrote in the `with` step and possibly overwrite whichever ones I pulled in earlier. I notice the `ls()` command only looks at vars defined inside the `with` step, but how can I concatenate them into a dataframe?

As an example of desired output:

```
set.seed(123)
myDat <- data.frame('x'=rnorm(3))
y <- with(myDat, {
  xgt0 <- x > 0
  x2 <- x^2
  foo()
})

print(y)
          x1  xgt0         x2
1 -0.5604756 FALSE 0.31413295
2 -0.2301775 FALSE 0.05298168
3  1.5587083  TRUE 2.42957161
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `within` like this:

```
set.seed(123)
myDat <- data.frame('x'=rnorm(3))

within(myDat, {
  xgt0 <- x > 0
  x2 <- x^2
})
```

giving:

```
           x         x2  xgt0
1 -0.5604756 0.31413295 FALSE
2 -0.2301775 0.05298168 FALSE
3  1.5587083 2.42957161  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 transform(myDat,xgt0=x > 0,x2= x^2)
           x  xgt0         x2
1 -0.5604756 FALSE 0.31413295
2 -0.2301775 FALSE 0.05298168
3  1.5587083  TRUE 2.42957161
```